# Java Web Sart Ubuntu 12.1. Load resource (image)

Tags: java, ubuntu, embedded-resource, java-web-start

I have a game that runs well on Windows and Mac but in Ubuntu it doesn't find the image(s). That's exactly the problem, it doesn't find the image.

I'm trying to run this on Ubuntu 12.1 with Java Web Start

This is what I use to load an image:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("pixelapp/wavelogy/images/boat.jpg");
```

My package is pixelapp.wavelogy

This is my code snippet in case you REALLY need it:

```
    String folder = "pixelapp/wavelogy/images/"; 

    fileName[count] = folder + "boat.jpg"; 

    pTex[count] = TextureIO.newTexture( 
                            cl.getResource(fileName[count]), false, null);
```

END OF CODE SNIPPET.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT:

```
Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type.
Error loading texture pixelapp/wavelogy/images/redboat.jpg
Error loading texture pixelapp/wavelogy/images/pinkboat.jpg

Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pixelapp.wavelogy.Wavelogy.display(Wavelogy.java:2739)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:373)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:358)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:280)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:655)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:594)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:543)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:74)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:142)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$1.run(FPSAnimator.java:128)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: true, open (no close attempt): 2/2, reusable (open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 2)
X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 2
X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x927bf60, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
X11Util: Open[1]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x9207ba8, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
```

Comment: do you get any error/exception? or just a resource/file not found exception and/or the visible lack of images?

Comment: What does "doesn't find the image" mean?

Comment: @acostache It just says nullPointer right after the snippet I pasted above here. It's clearly not finding the image(s).

Comment: Enable the Java Console to see what happens.  It may be a upper/lowercase difference on on of the file names.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen pixelapp/wavelogy/images/boat.jpg This is how it finds the image on Windows and Mac. If I do this src/pixelapp/wavelogy/images/boat.jpg it doesn't find it. Or this pixelapp/wavelogyworngpath/imagesmoreworngpath/boat.jpg it doesn't find it.

Comment: windows and Mac have case-insentisive file systems.  Linux have case-sensitive.  Double- check

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen My mac computer is case sensitive and I double checked now, so I would have caught that.

Comment: HFS is case insensitive. What did the console say?

Comment: What do you mean by HFS?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not work if you tried just:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/some_image.jpg");
```

As i suppose your class is in the pixelapp.wavelogy package, so i the pixelapp/wavelogy folder, and in there you have a images folder as well.